# Manually calling a library from a script

Tags: javascript, jquery, featherlight.js

I'm trying to manually call a featherlight library to make a popup from a script but not shure how to make it. The documentation says:

> In cases where you don't want an Element to act as Trigger you can
>   call Featherlight manually. You can use this for example in an ajax
>   callback to display the response data.
>
> $.featherlight($content, configuration);

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validate_help_form() {
        valid = true;
        if (document.help_form.username.value == "") {
            $.featherlight('Error message', $.featherlight.defaults);
            valid = false;
        }
        return valid;
    }
</script>
```

So what should I pass instead of configuration Object to make it work?

Comment: can you try like `$.featherlight('Error message', {});` i.e. pass an empty object.

Comment: @vijayP it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your content should be either HTML (e.g. `"<p>Error message</p>"`, a jQuery selector (e.g. `"div.my-class p"`, which 'Error message' is taken for), etc... Read the doc for the different types of contents